# Cross tabulation where rows correspond to unique values in x and columns correspond to unique values in y in R

Tags: r, pivot-table

long time lurker, first time user.

In short, I am looking for a function similar to "crosstab" in Matlab, but in R. In the Matlab example (this is taken from Matlab's cross-tabulate page), let's say I have two vectors: `x = [1 1 2 3 1]` and  `y = [1 2 5 3 1]`. Using the function `crosstab(x,y)` will result in a `3x4` table, where "rows in table correspond to the three distinct values in x, and the columns correspond to the four distinct values in y."

```
     2     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
```

Thank you!

i tried messing around with `xtabs(x + y)` but the output are sums of unique values

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to `R` community.

Try something like -

```
  x = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
  y = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 1)
  table(x, y)
```

And you will get

```
   y
x   1 2 3 5
  1 2 1 0 0
  2 0 0 0 1
  3 0 0 1 0
```

Or you can use `ftable` for better formatting.

```
ftable(x, y)

  y 1 2 3 5
x          
1   2 1 0 0
2   0 0 0 1
3   0 0 1 0
```